# removeAttr doesn't remove disabled attribute in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have the following code that unlocks the dropdown by removing the disabled attribute with the removeAttr function. This example doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox 24 for Ubuntu. However it works perfectly fine if added an alert after the RemoveAttr function as shown in the next example:

```
        $("#dropdown1").change(function() {
        $('#dropdown2').find('option').remove().end();
        if (obj[$(this).val()] !== undefined)
        {

            $('#dropdown2').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#dropdown2').append('<option></option>' + obj[$(this).val()]);
            $('#dropdown2').attr('required', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#dropdown2').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#dropdown2').attr('required', false);
        }

    });
```

Working example:

```
        $("#dropdown1").change(function() {
        $('#dropdown2').find('option').remove().end();
        if (obj[$(this).val()] !== undefined)
        {

            $('#dropdown2').removeAttr('disabled');
            alert("REMOVED");
            $('#dropdown2').append('<option></option>' + obj[$(this).val()]);
            $('#dropdown2').attr('required', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#dropdown2').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#dropdown2').attr('required', false);
        }

    });
```

Example with .prop doesn't work as well:

```
        $("#dropdown1").change(function() {
        $('#dropdown2').find('option').remove().end();
        if (obj[$(this).val()] !== undefined)
        {
            $('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#dropdown2').append('<option></option>' + obj[$(this).val()]);
            $('#dropdown2').attr('required', true);

        }
        else
        {
            $('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#dropdown2').attr('required', false);
        }

    });
```

Comment: There is great documentation about .attr()  method... `To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.` Just FYI, don't use removeProp() to replace removeAttr(), set property to false instead

Comment: can you share the related html

Comment: and the value of `obj`

Comment: If the problem remains you should create a http://jsfiddle.net reproducing this problem

Comment: All right, it looks like the Select2 plugin is messing up with those dropdowns. As soon as removed, everything works fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DcunN/7/   When  you remove the Select2 from javascript, it unblocks the second dropdown with no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the disabled property status

to enable

```
$('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', false);
```

to disable

```
$('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', true);
```

Read: [Attributes vs. Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Comment: Same thing, still doesn't work:        $("#dropdown1").change(function() {
            $('#dropdown2').find('option').remove().end();
            if (obj[$(this).val()] !== undefined)
            {
                $('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#dropdown2').append('<option></option>' + obj[$(this).val()]);
                $('#dropdown2').attr('required', true);
                
            }
            else
            {
                $('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#dropdown2').attr('required', false);
            }

        });

Answer (score 3):

From the (documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#entry-longdesc):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or **disabled** state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

So you should use the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function instead.

```
$('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', false); // Enables the element
$('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', true ); // Disables the element
```

Comment: Same problem. Doesnt work

Comment: @user1029829  If the problem remains you should create a jsfiddle.net reproducing this problem

Answer (score 1):

use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('#dropdown2').prop('disabled', false);
```

disable true make disable the element and disable false Enable the element

Comment: Same problem. Doesn't work.